# Problem adding barriers programmatically to a ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I have two XML based barriers used to separate some buttons in a calendar I'm building. Here's the XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/teamScheduleConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPreviousMonth"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/previousMonth"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/teamScheduleCurrentMonth"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teamScheduleCurrentMonth"
        style="@style/textViewGeneral"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="July 2019"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonNextMonth"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonPreviousMonth"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNextMonth"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/nextMonth"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/teamScheduleCurrentMonth"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/monthSelectorBarrier"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="buttonPreviousMonth,teamScheduleCurrentMonth,buttonNextMonth" />


    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/closeButtonBarrier"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:barrierDirection="top"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="teamScheduleCloseButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/monthSelectorBarrier" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/teamScheduleCloseButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/CloseButton"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/closeButtonBarrier" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="211dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Next I'm trying to programmatically add a new barrier for each new row of days in the calendar:

```
Barrier newRow = new Barrier(getContext());
int barrierId = View.generateViewId();
newRow.setId(barrierId);
newRow.setType(Barrier.BOTTOM);
layout.addView(newRow);
```

Let's say I've created two new barriers, 1 and 2. When I constrain some TextViews to "@+id/monthSelectorBarrier", they show up correctly. But when I constrain them to barrier 1 they all go to the top of the view:

[image: Barrier]

I'm setting the first new barrier to sit directly under "@+id/monthSelectorBarrier" using code similar to the below, but it still goes to the top of the ConstraintLayout.

Here's the code for setting a programatically created barrier to sit underneath another programatically created barrier (allDays is an int array of the IDs of the TextViews, so I can add them to each barrier):

```
constraintSet.clone(layout);

constraintSet.connect(2, ConstraintSet.TOP, 1, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
constraintSet.connect(2, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
constraintSet.connect(2, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END);

constraintSet.connect(allDays[i], ConstraintSet.TOP, 2, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

constraintSet.applyTo(layout);
```

What do I need to change to get all of the barriers to line up underneath each other correctly?

Comment: I don't think that you can add a barrier to _ConstraintLayout_ like a normal view. Try [ConstraintSet.html#createBarrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html#createBarrier(int,%2520int,%2520int,%2520int...)).

Comment: You can actually do it. I've been moved onto another project for the moment but I plan on making a blog post and then posting the answer to this question here. Basically, you need to all of your barriers and views to the layout before you change the constraint set. Then so long as you build a chain and add your views it does actually work. It just took a lot of trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

1. You forgot to set the `referenceIds` in your programmatically added barrier:

```
Barrier newRow = new Barrier(getContext());
int barrierId = View.generateViewId();
newRow.setId(barrierId);
newRow.setType(Barrier.BOTTOM);

// add the ids of the views for the barrier
int[] referenceIds = allDays; 
newRow.setReferencedIds(referenceIds);

layout.addView(newRow);
```

2. You need to set the constraints to the barrier's generated viewId:

```
...
constraintSet.connect(yourView.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, barrierId, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
...
```